# Trying to change DataView by user input with Google Visualization

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I've been developing this dataset with Google Visualization and so far I've managed to get it functional and halfway finished. There is only one chart that can change `chartType` by the user checking one of the yellow radio buttons on top. Below that group of yellow radio buttons are a group of blue radio buttons.

[image]

These blue radio buttons were intended to change `DataView`, unfortunately, I can't seem to get it working. I receive the following error:

> `Uncaught TypeError: a.Y is not a function(…)` .................    `jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:129`

1. I've tried downgrading to the deprecated Google API:
2. I've downgraded jQuery down to 2.2.2
3. I've placed the script before the closing `</body>` tag.
4. I've placed it in the `</head>`
5. I've gone insane.

[<kbd>PLUNKER</kbd>]

#### SNIPPET

```css
<!--THIS PART REMOVED-->
  </header>

  <section id="ii">
    <h1>Sources</h1>
    <figure id='chart'></figure>

  </section>
  <footer>&nbsp;</footer>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var options = {
      backgroundColor: {
        fill: 'transparent',
        stroke: '#000000',
        strokeWidth: 0
      },
      tooltip: {
        textStyle: {
          color: '0000FF'
        },
        trigger: 'focus'
      },
      animation: {
        "startup": true,
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'out'
      },
      title: 'Percentage of Americans in Favor of / Opposed to Same-sex Marriage (2001-16)',
      titleTextStyle: {
        color: 'gold',
        fontSize: 18
      },
      hAxis: {
        textStyle: {
          color: 'cyan'
        },
        title: 'Year',
        titleTextStyle: {
          color: 'gold',
          fontSize: 22
        },
        format: '####'
      },
      vAxis: {
        textStyle: {
          color: 'cyan'
        },
        title: 'Percentage of Sub-Population that Approves of Same-sex Marriage',
        titleTextStyle: {
          color: 'gold',
          fontSize: 16
        },
        maxValue: 1,
        format: '#%'

      },
      legend: {
        textStyle: {
          color: 'white'
        }
      }

    }
    var query;
    var chart;
    var data;
    var view;
    var formatter;
    var main;
    var selChart;
    var selGroup;
    var visual;
    google.charts.load('current', {
      'packages': ['corechart', 'line']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EY13wZB9IUet4e5gVeMEFLQcHdNfr--S4j741XVAfxo/gviz/tq?gid=1104711743&range=A:T');
      query.send(function(response) {
        if (response.isError()) {
          alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' - ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
          return;
        }
        data = response.getDataTable();
        visual = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
          pattern: '#%'
        });
        formatter.format(data, 1);
        formatter.format(data, 2);
        formatter.format(data, 3);
        formatter.format(data, 4);
        formatter.format(data, 5);
        formatter.format(data, 6);
        formatter.format(data, 7);
        formatter.format(data, 8);
        formatter.format(data, 9);
        formatter.format(data, 10);
        formatter.format(data, 11);
        formatter.format(data, 12);
        formatter.format(data, 13);
        formatter.format(data, 14);
        formatter.format(data, 15);
        formatter.format(data, 16);
        formatter.format(data, 17);
        formatter.format(data, 18);
        formatter.format(data, 19);
        chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
        chart.draw(visual, options);
      });
    }

    $('#chartOpt').on('change', selectChart);

    function selectChart() {
      chartSel = $("input[name='chart']:checked").val();
      main = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        containerId: 'chart'
      });
      switch (chartSel) {
        case '1':
          main.setChartType('LineChart');
          main.setOptions(options);
          main.setDataTable(data);
          main.draw();
          break;
        case '2':
          main.setChartType('LineChart');
          main.setOptions(options);
          main.setDataTable(data);
          main.draw();
          break;
        case '3':
          main.setChartType('ColumnChart');
          main.setOptions(options);
          main.setDataTable(data);
          main.draw();
          break;
        case '4':
          main.setChartType('ScatterChart');
          main.setOptions(options);
          main.setDataTable(data);
          main.draw();
          break;
      }
    }

    $('#groupOpt').on('change', selectGroup);

    function selectGroup() {
      groupSel = $("input[name='group']:checked").val();
      view = new google.visualization.DataView({
        containerId: 'chart'
      });
      switch (groupSel) {
        case '0':
          view.setColumns([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);
          view.setOptions(options);
          view.setDataTable(data);
          view.draw();
          break;
        case '1':
          view.setColumns([0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);
          view.setOptions(options);
          view.setDataTable(data);
          view.draw();
          break;
        case '2':
          view.setColumns([0, 10, 11, 12]);
          view.setOptions(options);
          view.setDataTable(data);
          view.draw();
          break;
        case '3':
          view.setColumns([0, 13, 14, 15]);
          view.setOptions(options);
          view.setDataTable(data);
          view.draw();
          break;
        case '4':
          view.setColumns([0, 16, 17]);
          view.setOptions(options);
          view.setDataTable(data);
          view.draw();
          break;
        case '5':
          view.setColumns([0, 18, 19]);
          view.setOptions(options);
          view.setDataTable(data);
          view.draw();
          break;
      }
    }
  </script>
  <!--<script src='gvis-api.js'></script>-->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the code is failing here when trying to create the `DataView`...

```
function selectGroup() {
  groupSel = $("input[name='group']:checked").val();
  view = new google.visualization.DataView({  // <-- fails here
    containerId: 'chart'
  });
  switch (groupSel) {
    case '0':
      view.setColumns([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);
      view.setOptions(options);  // <- view doesn't have this method
      view.setDataTable(data);   // <- view doesn't have this method
      view.draw();               // <- view doesn't have this method
      break;
    case '1':
      ...
```

i think you have `DataView` confused with `ChartWrapper`

first, the constructor for a `DataView` only accepts a `DataTable` or another `DataView`,
not a `containerId`

changing to a `ChartWrapper` does make sense for the code that is there
but `ChartWrapper` doesn't have a method for `setColumns`

use `setView` instead
also need to set a `chartType`

```
function selectGroup() {
  groupSel = $("input[name='group']:checked").val();
  view = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({  // <-- change to ChartWrapper
    containerId: 'chart',
    chartType: 'LineChart'                        // <-- set chartType
  });
  switch (groupSel) {
    case '0':
      view.setView({columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]});   // <-- use setView, note object arg
      view.setOptions(options);
      view.setDataTable(data);
      view.draw();
      break;
    case '1':
    ...
```

this should remove the error...

Comment: just made small edit to `setView` and different error being sent for column index, may need to rethink `selectGroup` -- recommend setting chart type and group in same function from both listeners...

Comment: Thank you, sir. And once again you are correct, I just fixed it before you posted. I combined user inputs and used `ChartWrapper` to do everything. Instead of using `DataView`, I used `.setDataSourceUrl` (it just occurred to me that I had individual sheets already made sitting at GSheets.).

Comment: LoL that's spooky.